# Sharing variable between functions

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having hard time trying to share a variable between javascript functions.

I basically have an object with 3 functions: one to fetch the data, one to render a chart and the third one to manipulate the chart itself.

My code looks like

```
 this.ChartManager = {
      plotChart: function(chartName) {
       ...
       ChartManager.createChart(seriesOptions);
      },

    createChart: function(seriesOptions) {
      var chart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
       ...
      });
    },

    toggleSeries: function(n) {
      current_series = chart.series[n];
      ...
    }
 };
```

But when in ToggleSeries I try to access the chart variable I get an 'undefined' error message.

How can I make the chart variable accessible from ToggleSeries?

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

**UPDATE** - My working code is

```
this.ChartManager = {
      plotChart: function(chartName) {
       ...
       ChartManager.createChart(seriesOptions);
      },

    createChart: function(seriesOptions) {
       $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
       ...
      });
    },

    toggleSeries: function(n) {
    var current_series = $('#container').highcharts().series[n];
      ...
    }
 };
```

Comment: So all works properly ?

Answer (score 1):

Define variables in the object, and use them in any member function.

```
 this.ChartManager = {
    globalVar1:0,
    chart:0,
    plotChart: function(chartName) {
       ...
       ChartManager.createChart(seriesOptions);
      },

    createChart: function(seriesOptions) {
      this.chart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
       ...
      });
    },

    toggleSeries: function(n) {
      current_series = this.chart.series[n];
      ...
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't - a variable defined inside of a function stays inside that function's scope. You'd have to move that variable either into the global scope or attach it to an object accessible from the current scope.